# XSS via breaking tag parameter using no equal sign

Tags: xss

I have found a XSS candidate so the GET request to non-existing page with path like this `http://example.com/page/blabla"onclick` generates the following HTML: `404 <a href="/page/blabla"onclick>`. However, the equal sign urlencodes and I get the following HTML when trying to exploit it: `<a href="/page/blabla"onclick%3falert()">`. Can I exploit this bug in case of equal sign filtering?

Comment: Sounds [similar to this](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/98025/8340).

Answer (score 0):

Try with Internet Explorer 9, as this does not automatically encode query string characters.

e.g.

```
http://example.com/page/blabla" onclick="alert(123)
```

which should be rendered as

```
<a href="/page/blabla" onclick="alert(123)">
```

You might need to [disable IE's XSS filter](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/169672-internet-explorer-cross-site-scripting-xss-filter-turn-off.html).